# In libgdx, correct placement of ShapeRenderer begin and end

Tags: libgdx

My question is whether I should place `sRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);` and `sRenderer.end();` outside of `Shape`? so they're not called for every `Shape.draw()`

Or is the approach below ok in terms of performance?

Snippet from one of my `Shape`s ..

```
private Body body; // initialized elsewhere
private float width = 1.0f;
private float height = 1.0f;

public void draw(ShapeRenderer sRenderer) {
    sRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    sRenderer.setColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    sRenderer.identity();
    sRenderer.translate(getBody().getPosition().x, getBody().getPosition().y, 0);
    sRenderer.rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, (float) Math.toDegrees(getBody().getAngle()));
    sRenderer.rect(-getWidth(), -getHeight(), getWidth() * 2, getHeight() * 2);
    sRenderer.end();
}
```

In my `Level` class, theres a `draw()` method called every frame e.g

```
for (Body body : bodies) {
    if (body.getUserData() instanceof Shape){
        ((Shape) body.getUserData()).draw(getShapeRenderer());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call `begin()`,`identity()`, `translate()`, `rotate()`, or etc., it will trigger a new flush to the GPU the next time you draw something with the shape renderer. So in your case, moving `begin()` and `end()` out of the loop won't have a very significant impact.

If this is a bottle neck, you could try calculating your rectangle corners independently from the shape renderer and submitting four lines to the shape renderer, using world space coordinates instead of local coordinates like you're doing now. Then move `begin()` and `end()` out of the loop like you suggested and benchmark the difference. I'm not sure which would be faster in your case. This would reduce draw calls but you'd be translating more points on the CPU as well.